# IISReset attempt failed

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, iis

I have tried to do a iisreset in my server, but it fails..

> Attempting stop... Internet services successfully stopped Attempting
>   start... Restart attempt failed. The IIS Admin Service or the World
>   Wide Web Publishing Service, or a service dep endent on them failed to
>   start.  The service, or dependent services, may had an error during
>   its startup or may be disabled.

Comment: try to reboot the server and then check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reset the IIS once again and it will run normally again

The message says "The service, or dependent services, may had an error during its startup or may be disabled." This may happen in IIS 7 / 7.5 because WAS (Windows Process Activation Service) may be taking some time to refresh.

The best way to make sure your IIS related services restarts successfully is to use "net stop W3SVC" and "net start W3SVC" as an Administrator.